# why wont mt amature go to another layer?

Tags: layers

Im trying to move my amature/meta rig and it let me do it then i accidentally pressed ctrl + z and then tried it again and it woldnt go to another layer it would say it would however it was still in the same layer

Comment: Please provide your file on blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com and provide screenshots of what you tried and the problem.

Comment: I SOLVED IT I PRESSED RANDOM BUTTONS AND THEN IT FIXED

Answer (score 2):

You might be confusing bone layers with scene layers. An armature has it's own layer system that is used for it's bones. You may not notice at first but the bone layers pop-up has more layer buttons than the scene layers, there are 32 bone layers and 20 scene layers.

[image: change bone layer]

Pressing <kbd>M</kbd> while in pose mode will bring up the change bone layers option. You need to be in object mode when you press <kbd>M</kbd> to move the armature object to another scene layer.

You can also use the object properties to move any object to another scene layer at any time.

[image: object layers]

Comment: thats still not doing anything  to move it to another layer

Comment: If you have multiple or all layers visible in the 3dview then moving an objeft to another layer will not be visually different. You can also have an object located on multiple layers.